# Fastest way to get the prefix of a random shuffle in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

As an example, say we want a random 13-card hand from a 52-card deck.
We can randomly shuffle all 52 cards and extract the first 13:

```
    import numpy as np
    cards = np.arange(52)
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    rng.shuffle(cards)
    hand = cards[:13]
```

Is there a faster way given that we only need a prefix of the shuffled result?
(Including when the array sizes are larger.)

Answer (score 1):

You could randomly choose from the range, without shuffling:

```
np.random.choice(cards, size=13, replace=False)
```

#edit:

however, actually timing this:

```
%%timeit -r 10 -n 10

rng.shuffle(cards)
hand = cards[:13]

The slowest run took 7.99 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
8.14 µs ± 8.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

vs:

```
%%timeit -r 10 -n 10

np.random.choice(cards, size=13, replace=False)

22.2 µs ± 7.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

vs:

```
%%timeit -r 10 -n 10

np.random.shuffle(cards)
hand = cards[:13]

3.18 µs ± 699 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: `numpy.random.choice` is stuck with an absurdly awful implementation of `replace=False` due to backward compatibility constraints. The new `numpy.random.Generator` API has a much better implementation.

Comment: @warped Thanks for the `timeit` experiments.  It seems that setting `-n 10000` results in more stable numbers; I get:  `[1.62 µs, 8.4 µs, 1.29 µs]`.

Comment: For `hand = rng.choice(cards, size=13, replace=False)`, I get `7.26 µs` which is similar to `np.random.choice`.